# Opening and closing of details summary element according to array index

Tags: html, css, typescript, svelte

The problem is how to open and close the details and summary tag according to array index in svelte js. I want that details will be closed when clicked on another details element.

I tried binding open attribute of details element but it will toggle all the details elements which are created with each loop in svelte. I am expecting it will open and close according to its array index.

```html
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    let isOpen = true;
</script>

<h1>
    The details is {isOpen ? 'open' : 'not open'}
</h1>
{#each Array(10)as _}
<details bind:open={isOpen}>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    <p>
        Something small enough to escape casual notice.
    </p>
</details>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. define a local variable that tracks the currently open index and listen to `toggle` to update it:

```html
<script>
    // ...
    let opened = null;
</script>

{#each items as item, i}
    <details open={opened == i}
        on:toggle={e => {
            if (e.target.open)
                opened = i;
        }}>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e66766732a92491abc0698f01a0a599c?version=4.2.0)